# Tesseract doesn't recognize certain pictures. Python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

Tesseract works fine when I use other pictures but whenever I use this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6lW4.png) it doesn't recognize the picture.
Can someone explain me why please?

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import time
import random
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard = Controller()  # Create the controller

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread("capture5.png")
#img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 300))
cv2.imshow("capture5", img)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, all I needed to do was add this code to my script.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
 img, config=("-c tessedit"
              "_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
              " --psm 10"
              " "))
```